# What remoting mechanism the get-service -computername is using?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I read at https://ss64.com/ps/get-service.html under the -computername parameter that "This parameter does not rely on PowerShell remoting."

What kind of remoting it is using then?
Is it using a different port or protocol?
What is the difference compare to the Invoke-command`s remoting?

Thank you.

Comment: it uses DCOM iirc same as the WMI cmdlets

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.